# How to fetch youtube videos using Oauth 2.0 in yii?

Tags: yii, youtube, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

Hi guys i want to fetch videos from my account , from play list, categories, and want to display them on my site. If i upload any video on you tube . That should display on my site. Please help me with this. I am **using yii 1.1**

Answer (score 0):

1)[Create a channel in youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861?hl=en).

2)Embed following code in your webpage code.

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=MyChannelName&synd=open&w=320&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>
```

3)Replace the **MyChannelName** with your original channel name.

Reference:

[YouTube on your site](http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite)

[Embed YouTube Channel](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=4c414f514bc3f690&hl=en)

**Edit**

If you must do it via `OAUTH2`, try  [Google APIs Client Library for Youtube](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/examples/youtube)

```
<?php
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
session_start();

/* You can acquire an OAuth 2 ID/secret pair from the API Access tab on the Google APIs Console
  <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
  <https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2>
Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
          $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi harikrishnan i want to perform this using google api and oauth

Comment: @Vikky   You can do this without that...It's pretty straightforward..Then Why are you going for that?